# Get bootstrap progress bar aria-valuenow value and modify it using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So basically, bootstrap offers this progressbar component on the run:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

You can modify the value of the progressbar via `aria-valuenow`.

What I did is get this using:

```
let progressbar = document.getElementsByClassName('progress').value();
```

And then on my onclick event, I want to add succeeding 25 for each currentstep:

```
   button[1].onclick = () => {
      current_step++;
      progressbar = progressbar + 25;
      let previous_step = current_step - 1;
      if(( current_step > 0) && (current_step <= 4)){
        button[0].style.display = "inline-block";
        step[current_step].style.display = "block";
        step[previous_step].style.display = "none";

        if (current_step == 4){
          button[2].style.display = "inline-block";
        }

      } else {
        if(current_step > 4){
            form.onsubmit = () => { return true }
        }
      }
   }
```

But this one did not work and it doesn't add 25 for each addition of step or click of the button.

How can i fix this in order to make it add 25 on each step on a click of a button?

Answer (score 2):

First, the "aria" attributes is for accessability. Its the style attribute "width" that sets the width, example style="width: 25%".

```
let progressbar = document.getElementsByClassName('progress').value();
```

In your example the element with class "progress" is a div without any value attribute.

You must fetch the current value of the progress bar element with class "progress-bar". Then you can increase it and set the new value to the progess-bar element.